# react state not. updating back to initial state after onchange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im having trouble updating the react array objects on this particular form i have.  Heres my code:

```
    import { useState } from 'react';
    import { useEffect } from "react";

function MyForm() {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({})
    const [indexes, setIndex] = useState([]);
    const [sectorName, setSectorName] = useState('')

    const testData = [
        {name: "jack", age: "39", sector: "finance"},
        {name: "aaron", age: "42", sector: "health-care"},
        {name: "peter", age: "36", sector: "unemployed"},
        {name: "jason", age: 50, sector: "finance"},
        {name: "mike", age: 40, sector: "health-care"},
        {name: "rahul", age: 45, sector: "unemployed"},
    ]

    const filter = (value) => testData.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => {
        let result = cur.sector.startsWith(value) ? [...acc, idx]: acc;
        return result;
    }, [])
    

    
    const handleNameChange = event => {
    
    const value = event.target.value;
    
    setSectorName(value);

}

useEffect( () => {
    console.log(sectorName)
    var idx = filter(sectorName);
    setIndex(idx);
    console.log(indexes);
}, [sectorName])


const handleChange = event => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;
        setInputs(previousState => {
            return {...previousState, [name]: value}})

    }



const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(`the name you entered was: ${inputs.sector} and your age is ${inputs.age}`)
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label> Enter the sector:
            <input 
                type="text"
                name="sector"
                value={inputs.sector || ""}
                onChange={handleNameChange} 
            />
            </label>
            <label> Enter your age
                <input
                    type="number"
                    name="age"
                    value={inputs.age || ""}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            <br></br>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    )
}
```

Basically, im trying to filter on the testData object.  if the user types "fi" in the sector field it will return the indexes of the data in the array that which is [0, 3] since "finance" is part of the sector.  if no match is found, it should return [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], i.e all indexes.

Now, when i type "fi", or "un" its correctly giving me the correct index.

So, for example, suppose i type "fi".  its returning index [0, 3].  but after deleting the value from the field, (its empty), im expecting the array to give me [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] but instead, its stuck at [0, 3].  I can see this in my console.log() statement inside the. useEffect.  so when i delete all the characters in the field, this line gives me the correct value:

```
let res = filter("");
console.log(res);
```

since value is empty string.  but setting the index and its still showing [0, 3] instead of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].  can someone please help?  thanks

edited to make it more clear

Comment: The `indexes` state doesn’t update immediately as soon as you call `setIndex()`, the new state value is only available on the next render. You should see that `idx` has the correct value

Comment: yes idx does have the correct value

Comment: oh. oops k i set another usetEffect and can see the value.